# sudo dpkg --configure -a error

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I cant seems to fix this kind of error

evrything fails when i install a package

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libllvm4.0 linux-headers-4.4.0-157 linux-headers-4.4.0-157-generic linux-image-4.4.0-103-generic linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic linux-image-4.4.0-127-generic linux-image-4.4.0-137-generic linux-image-4.4.0-138-generic linux-image-4.4.0-157-generic linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic
  linux-modules-4.4.0-157-generic linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-157-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-103-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-127-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-137-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-138-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-79-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-87-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-96-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-98-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  curl
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 11 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
24 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/139 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,688 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 1385987 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-103-generic (4.4.0-103.126) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-103-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-103-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-103-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-103-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-103-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/btrfs failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-103-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-103-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic (4.4.0-109.132) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-109-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-109-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-109-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-109-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-109-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/btrfs failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-109-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-127-generic (4.4.0-127.153) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-127-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-127-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-127-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-127-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-127-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/btrfs failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-127-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-127-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-137-generic (4.4.0-137.163) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-137-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-137-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-137-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-137-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-137-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/btrfs failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-137-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-137-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-138-generic (4.4.0-138.164) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-138-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-138-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-138-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-138-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-138-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/btrfs failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-138-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-138-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic (4.4.0-66.87) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-66-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-66-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-66-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-66-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-66-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/btrfs failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-66-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71-generic (4.4.0-71.92) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-71-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-71-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-71-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-71-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-71-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/btrfs failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-71-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-79-generic (4.4.0-79.100) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-79-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-79-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-79-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-79-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-79-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/btrfs failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-79-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-79-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-87-generic (4.4.0-87.110) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-87-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-87-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-87-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-87-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-87-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/btrfs failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-87-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-87-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-96-generic (4.4.0-96.119) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-96-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-96-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-96-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-96-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-96-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/btrfs failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-96-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-96-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-98-generic (4.4.0-98.121) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-98-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-98-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-98-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/btrfs failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-98-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-98-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-103-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-127-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-137-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-138-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-79-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-87-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-96-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-98-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
+++-=====================================-==========================================-============-===============================================================================
iF  initramfs-tools                       0.122ubuntu8.14                            all          generic modular initramfs generator (automation)
iF  linux-firmware                        1.157.22                                   all          Firmware for Linux kernel drivers
iU  linux-generic                         4.4.0.164.172                              amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
iF  linux-image-4.4.0-103-generic         4.4.0-103.126                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iF  linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic         4.4.0-109.132                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iF  linux-image-4.4.0-127-generic         4.4.0-127.153                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iF  linux-image-4.4.0-137-generic         4.4.0-137.163                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iF  linux-image-4.4.0-138-generic         4.4.0-138.164                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iF  linux-image-4.4.0-159-generic         4.4.0-159.187                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
iF  linux-image-4.4.0-164-generic         4.4.0-164.192                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
iF  linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic          4.4.0-71.92                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iF  linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic          4.4.0-96.119                               amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rH  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-103-generic   4.4.0-103.126                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rH  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic   4.4.0-109.132                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rH  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-127-generic   4.4.0-127.153                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rH  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-137-generic   4.4.0-137.163                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rH  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-138-generic   4.4.0-138.164                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rH  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic    4.4.0-66.87                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rH  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71-generic    4.4.0-71.92                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rH  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-79-generic    4.4.0-79.100                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rH  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-87-generic    4.4.0-87.110                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rH  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-96-generic    4.4.0-96.119                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rH  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-98-generic    4.4.0-98.121                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-generic                   4.4.0.164.172                              amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

Comment: `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'`  please.

Comment: added it below @nobody

Comment: Sorry  I am  on mobile.  First you need repair initramfs¬tools. You can download over Ubuntu package search

Comment: @nobody not sure how to do that, do you have samples?

Comment: You can download `initramfs-tools` via packages.ubuntu.com to repair your package

Answer (score 0):

This error is not since yesterday. Make a backup from your important data.

```
wget -c http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/initramfs-tools/initramfs-tools_0.122ubuntu8.14_all.deb
```

Install the package directly with dpkg.

```
sudo dpkg -i initramfs-tools_0.122ubuntu8.14_all.deb
```

Control with

```
dpkg -l | grep initramfs-tools
```

If the package is correct installt. Should look `ii  initramfs-tools 0.122ubuntu8.14`. This is important.
Many kernels are not in good condition.

next step

```
df -h;df -i
```

Shows, how many space and inodes are free. Particularly important if you have an individual /boot partition.

If you have enough space

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt -f install
```

If not you have to remove some packages.

checkout the running kernel with

```
uname -a
```

Now get rid from kernelpackages with unclean state.

```
 dpkg -l 'linux-[ihs]*' | sed '/^iF/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\([-0-9]*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d' > | tee removing-kernel
```

and

```
dpkg -l 'linux-[ihs]*' | sed '/^rH/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\([-0-9]*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d' | tee -a  removing-kernel
```

`cat removing-kernel` should content the following packages. Important.

```
linux-image-4.4.0-103-generic         
linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic         
linux-image-4.4.0-127-generic         
linux-image-4.4.0-137-generic         
linux-image-4.4.0-138-generic         
linux-image-4.4.0-159-generic         
linux-image-4.4.0-164-generic         
linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic          
linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic         
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-103-generic   
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic   
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-127-generic   
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-137-generic   
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-138-generic  
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic   
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71-generic    
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-79-generic    
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-87-generic    
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-96-generic    
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-98-generic
```

Now remove them with

```
cat removing-kernel | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

apt-get purge this without any need.

Moving on. Now let see how many kernels on your system.

```
dpkg -l 'linux-[ihs]*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\([-0-9]*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d'
```

List all installt kernel besides your running kernel.

If so,

```
sudo apt purge $(dpkg -l 'linux-[ihs]*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\([-0-9]*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d')
```

After that

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt -f install
```

If something is not working let us know and stop.